# get image data from custom report item(ssrs control)

Tags: reporting-services

Does anybody know how to get image data from inside custom report item?

I want to enable users of my component to set image (background image for example) for the component to use. I've managed to create property with ImageSource type, but I reason that I need to read Source and Value, and than retrive the image data itself(since there is nothing in the ImageSource interface to access it).

I suspect that there should be a common interface for all types of sources, but if I need to use something like EmbeddedImageCollection that is also fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in Short : View Code and copy and paste the    tag into the embedded images tag